# pattern recognition with eight characters

Tags: linux, perl, awk, sed

I have  patterns list in a file. The pattern is composed of eight characters composed of combination of 0,1,2, or 3. I just want to grep those number which contains at least five 3's and rest is 2's. Order of characters does not matter, ie it can grep 33333333, 33333222, 32323333, and others combination.

file1

```
33333333
22333333
23232333
13323332
22233333
22323233
10111111
```

output

```
33333333
22333333
23232333
13323332
22233333
```

Could you kindly suggest me any command in linux, awk, sed, perl. Thanks

Comment: Eigth questions (nine including this one) with zero votes and zero accepted answers. Didn't you like any of the answers you got in previous questions? Do you know how StackOverflow works?

Comment: Why is `13323332` in your required output?

Comment: Sorry for mistake. It is a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do what you ask. It uses `tr///` to count the characters, and prints the line only if there are at least five `3`s and no `1`s  or `0`s (so the rest must be `2`s)

```
perl -ne 'print if tr/3// >= 5 and tr/10// == 0' myfile.txt
```

Comment: @LeeDuhem: Thanks. I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Simply counting the characters is clearer and less fragile.

However, just as a point of comparison, here is a regex solution.  Even though this is shorter, I'd still vote for the other.

```
perl -ne 'print if /^(2*3){5}[23]*$/' myfile.txt
```

**Update - Breakdown of regex**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (m{
        ^           # Anchor at start of string
        (
            2*      # Any number of 2's
            3       # followed by a 3.
        ){5}        # group repeated 5 times. (ensures we have at least 5 3's)
        [23]*       # Any number of 2 or 3's
        $           # Anchor at end of string
    }x) {
        print;
    }

}

__DATA__
33333333
22333333
23232333
13323332
22233333
22323233
10111111
```

Outputs:

```
33333333
22333333
23232333
22233333
```

Comment: Thanks for code. Could you kindly explain this (2*3){5}[23].

Comment: annotated version of the code included to explain the regex.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 'h;s/3/&/5;T;s/[23]//g;/^$/{g;p}' file
```

Copy the line, account for five `3`'s, remove all `3`'s and `2`'s and if the line is empty retrieve the copied line and print out.